# error starting container: API error (500): Could not attach to network hlf-ldap_basic: context deadline exceeded

Tags: ldap, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, openldap

I'm following this repo : https://github.com/fabric-devkit/demo-ldap
After running :

```
docker-compose build
```

I run `./start.sh` and after the chaincode is installed i,e. chaincode is instantiated it throws an error.

```
docker exec cli peer chaincode instantiate -o orderer.example.com:7050 -C mychannel -n minimalcc -l "$CC_RUNTIME_LANGUAGE" -v 1.0 -c '{"Args":["init", "admin", "10", "B", "10"]}' -P "OR ('Org1MSP.member')"
```